How to find out S3 Bucket last accessed time for last 180 days
How to find out S3 Bucket last accessed time for last 180 days which are all in inactive s3 buckets using boto3. i have gone through the documents but that didn't work assist me to achieve this, Thanks in advance!

The one way to find this out is by using AWS CloudTrail service that need to be enabled prior to access time.
Here is an example of how to get the timestamp:
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

client = boto3.client('cloudtrail')

# Start time last 180 days
end_time = datetime.now()
start_time = end_time - timedelta(days=180)

# Get events
response = client.lookup_events(
    LookupAttributes=[
        {
            'AttributeKey': 'ResourceName',
            'AttributeValue': 'your-bucket-name' # <-- put YOUR bucket name here
        },
    ],
    StartTime=start_time,
    EndTime=end_time,
)

# At this point `response['Events']` contains all events of the specified bucket
for event in response['Events']:
    print(event['EventTime'], event['EventName'])


See the full list of S3 events here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-logging-s3-info.html

Thanks for the response @ilya khrustalev im not getting any events  response is null printing like this {'Events': [], 'ResponseMetadata': but AWS CloudTrail service is enabled already.
